# How to take powerapps back environment in Azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powerapps, power-platform

How to take powerapps back environment in Azure devops ?

I need to take backup of environment before solution import into production environment so please explain the detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 techniques you can do backup.

1. Backup your entire enviornment (i.e each and every Table, it's customization)
2. Backup your soluttion (i.e only compoenet which you want to backup). In dynamics world we deploy solution i.e components. If you want to backup only account entity. Then create a empty solution in your target env, add account entity and export it as unmanaged. This will also be considered as backup (but only for your account entity). Note: In this case data is not backed up rather only customization (medatadat).

But I think you are looking for 1. technique.
Take a look at this [Ms article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/backup-restore-environments#system-backups) This will help you out

There is Pipeline Build Tools called [power platform build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tool-tasks) created by Ms [Power Platform Backup Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tool-tasks#power-platform-backup-environment)

Comment: This backup, I need to take from Azure devops pipeline

Comment: updated answer, you will need to use power platform build tools

Comment: Yes. I tried but I am getting the following error.The service principal with id 'for application * does not have permission to access the path 'https://10.0.5.7:20011/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments?`$expand=permissions&api-version=2020-0

Comment: Which permission has to give So I need this details

Comment: I think This is beyond the scope of question and lies in CI/CD knowledge. articles linked should guide you how to achieve your req. Please mark it as solved if this helps.

Comment: could you please mark this as solved.